# This pointer to print strings C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm sure there have been many similar questions asked, but since I'm not very familiar with C++, I don't exactly know what to look for/what to call it.

I've got a class which is trying to use a void method to print out an `std::string` it has a a public variable.  When I try, I get a lengthy error report of the following reported several times:

```
 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\ostream(785): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>        ]
```

`header`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
class Person
{
public:
    Person(void);
    Person(std::string);
    int myInt;
    std::string myString;
    ~Person(void);
    void SayHi();
    void MyName();
};
```

--
`cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream" 
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(void)
{
    myInt = 23;
}
Person::Person(std::string s)
{
    myString = s;
}
Person::~Person(void)
{
}
void Person::SayHi()
{
    std::cout<< "say hi" <<std::endl;
}
void Person::MyName()
{
    std::cout<< this->myString; //if this line is commented out, program runs fine
    std::cout<< "I can print to the console" <<std::endl;
}
```

--
main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>


int main() 
{

    Person p;
    Person p2 = Person("Darrin");
    p2.SayHi();
    p2.MyName();

}
```

I can print out the pointer `this` in the MyName method and intellisense pops up myString in the MyName method, why does it blow up when I compile it?

Comment: you don't include <string> in person.h or person.cpp, is this intended ?

Comment: Whops, just wanted to vote for closing..

Comment: @SirDarius >.< thanks, I'm just getting into c++ and not aware of some of the error messages.  We should close this question.

Comment: @KirilKirov And you did, but you have a gold C++ badge, so no other vote was needed.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: You cut out the actual error code (`C....`). Which is a shame, because that is very googlable.

Comment: @Borgleader - hm, this is something (relatively?) new, interesting. Thanks for the info, I didn't know what gave me the permission to mark it as duplicate without any other votes.